# How the inverse of this matrix be found?

Tags: matrices

How can the inverse of matrix 
$A = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 6&5\\5&4 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ be $A^{-1} = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} -4&5\\ 5&-6 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ where $\frac{1}{ad-bc} = \frac{1}{24-25} = \frac{1}{-1}$?

I thought that an inverse to this matrix was not possible, but my textbox and Wolfram Alpha says otherwise. Can someone tell me how this is possible, or if I have misunderstood the formula?

Comment: why did you think it was not possible?

Comment: If you multiply the two matrices, do you not get the identity matrix? What's the problem?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I didn't calculate 1/(-1) correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that this matrix is invertible in couple of ways.

For example:

1. $|A|=6\cdot4-5\cdot5=-1\neq0$
2. The rows of $A$ are linearly independent .
3. The columns of $A$ are linearly independent .
4. $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ (you can calculate the eigenvalues
   by finding the characteristic polynomial of $A$)
5. You have found a matrix $B$ s.t $AB=BA=I$

Comment: thanks for the great answer

Comment: @Sam you're welcome! I'm glad you liked it